# Let $f$ be smooth, then the "directional derivative" $df_x$ is linear.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This was mentioned in a casual comment. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be smooth, then its derivative at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is $$df_x(h) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th) - f(x)}{t}.$$ Now the derivative mapping $df_x : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth. In the case of $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, this seems right, since $(\nabla f_x, h_1 + h_2)$ assuming I take the standard partial derivatives (by that, I just mean taking the directional derivative at $e_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1,\dots,0)$). So my main issue is I can't see how additivity and scalar multiplication is satisfied in the difference quotient.

Comment: Both $f(x+th),\ f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector space. Everything seems to be properly defined.

Comment: So we have to assume $f$ is linear?

Comment: If $f$ is linear then you have $t^{-1}[f(x+th)-f(x)] = f(h)$.

Comment: So then what did you mean by "everything properly defined"?

Comment: You can add vectors and you can multiply by scalar

Comment: Ohh okay.......10char

Answer (score 0):

Since $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, we can view the mapping as
\begin{align}
f(x) =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x)\\
f_2(x)\\
\vdots\\
f_n(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
So, we the difference quotient looks like
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{f_1(x+th)-f_1(x)}{t}\\
\frac{f_2(x+th)-f_2(x)}{t}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{f_n(x+th)-f_n(x)}{t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which means if the $f$ is sufficiently smooth then
\begin{align}
df_x(h):=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
df_1(x)(h)\\
df_2(x)(h)\\
\vdots\\
df_n(x)(h)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
i.e. you are finding $n$ different directional derivatives of scalar functions.

**Remark**: $df_x(h)$ is linear in the sense that 
\begin{align}
h \longmapsto \underbrace{(h, h, \ldots, h)}_{n-\text{times}} \in (\mathbb{R}^m)^{\otimes n}
\end{align}
is linear and
\begin{align}
[df_1, df_2, \ldots, df_n](h, h, \ldots, h) 
\end{align}
is linear
where $[df_1, df_2, \ldots, df_n]$ is a $n$-linear map.

Comment: Aren't you listing $f(x)$ by standard bases?

Comment: What's wrong with choosing bases?

Comment: Don't we have to show that this is true independent of the bases?

Comment: When you first learn how to take a derivative or directional derivative in cal 3, you are always computing your derivative with respect to some basis (more appropriately, a globally defined orthogonal frame).